# Doubly Linked List with null objects at the beginning and end of the list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I was trying to create a doubly linked list with null objects at the beginnig and end of the list. What does null objects means at the beginning and end of the list. Does creating firstNode =null and lastNode == null will solve this problem or it means something different? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
// Creating a doubly linked list.
    doubleLinkedList = new DoubleLinkedList();

class DoubleLinkedList {

    private NewLink firstNode;
    private NewLink lastNode;
    private NewLink rootNode;

    // Initializing values in the Constructor for DoubleLinkedList
    public DoubleLinkedList() {

        rootNode  = null;
        firstNode = null;
        lastNode  = null;

    }

}



class NewLink {

    public String  data;
    public NewLink nextPointer;
    public NewLink previousPointer;

    public NewLink(String id) {

        data = id;

    }

    // Overriding toString method to return the actual data of the node
    public String toString() {

        return "{" + data + "} ";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information to determine if you were using the standard "LinkedList" collection, or implementing your own.  You also didn't give any idea exactly what you're trying to do, or what's going wrong.

ANYWAY:

Assuming you're interested in the standard LinkedList, here are some good tutorials:

- http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html
- http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/collections/Collection.html#ArrayListLinkedListClasses
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/143089-linked-list-tutorial/

And to your specific question: No.  There's seldom any need to explicitly set anything to "null".  Just create your container list, add stuff to it, and perform operations on the list items.

Comment: I am implementing on my own. I just want to create two null objects. one at the beginning of the list and the other at the end of the list. Everthing is clear I guess in the code itself.

Comment: Did you understand my actual question. What I am looking to do is create an empty doubly linked list with two null objects bascially. one at the beginning of the list and the other at the end of the list.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "null object".  There's a variable whose value is null; but that's another way of saying that it doesn't reference ANY object.

Comment: @David Wallace, So that means so far what I have did in my code is right according to you. But after creating this doubly linked list. anything that I will be inserting is between the first null objects and last null objects. So that way my code is right or something wrong? I have to insert data between null objects i.e between first(null) and last(null) node

Comment: Your code will be right (or not) when you write some code to insert the objects into the list.  Right now, since it doesn't really do anything, it's hard to label it as either right or wrong.  And please stop talking about "null objects", there's STILL no such thing.

Comment: If i've understood correctly firstNode is a reference to your first item in the list, which is the same as rootNode (ie - the entry point into the list). So, what is the point in having firstNode?

Comment: rootNode is nuthing here. I got confused with null object design pattern. That's why I posted this question. My code follow the null object design pattern if first and last node has to be null objects?